# What happens in a particle accelerator?

Tags: particle-physics, accelerator-physics, particle-accelerators

How is the particle accelerated? Is it by increasing its energy?
Is it only charged elementary particles that can be accelerated, because they are the only ones that can absorb photons and gain energy?

Comment: Don Lincoln of FermiLab did a series of videos on physics, including several on how accelerators work. See [Videos by Don Lincoln](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCfRa7MXBEsoJuAM8s6D8oKDPyBepBosS). Check numbers 45, 55, 57, and 59 - 62. Then you might look at 28, 29, 24, 85, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accelerating electrons via microwaves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/69778/accelerating-electrons-via-microwaves)

Answer (score 2):

A particle accelerator pushes particles with an electric field. For that reason, it only accelerates charged particles, although they need not be elementary. Particle accelerators employ classical electrodynamic principles, no quantum reasoning required. But relativity usually is.

Answer (score 2):

A direct [copy](https://www.energy.gov/articles/how-particle-accelerators-work) from the link explains it simply:

[image: part accel]

please read the link for details

Comment: That's one type (a synchrotron). There are others.

Comment: @JohnDoty sure , this is a simple to understand example